# Trying to track some information on those who rose from the dead on Good Friday

Tags: crucifixion, resurrection, resource-request, temple, good-friday

Many years ago I read that according to their records, it took the Temple two years to interview all the dead that were raised at the Crucifixion. Two of these people were rabbis or priests, a father and son who had both died within the previous six months, and were thus well known to the Temple staff.

It then seemed to me this would be why Christianity would grow like wildfire, but I cannot find the source for this, and I have been looking for years.

The Gospel of St. Mathew has this to say about those who rose from the dead on Good Friday.

> Jesus, when he had cried again with a loud voice, yielded up the ghost. And, behold, the veil of the temple was rent in twain from the top to the bottom; and the earth did quake, and the rocks rent; **and the graves were opened; and many bodies of the saints which slept arose, and came out of the graves after his resurrection, and went into the holy city, and appeared unto many.** Now when the centurion, and they that were with him, watching Jesus, saw the earthquake, and those things that were done, they feared greatly, saying, Truly this was the Son of God. ([Matthew 27: 50-54](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Bible_(King_James)/Matthew#27:33))

Is anyone familiar with this interviewing story?

Comment: I've never heard of anything like that. Sounds made up to me.

Comment: I vaguely remember a legend about this somewhere. But, it was years ago. I will try to find a source for you.